# How to disable ListView navigation through keyboard

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Can I somehow disable ListView items navigation through keyboard (arrow keys), and leave navigation with mouse and in code? Im new to WPF, but have some experience with WinForm so any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register the listView_PreviewKeyDown Event and set

```
    private void listView1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

For further infos on the pressed key (e.g. to disable only special keys) check the KeyEventArgs e.

Comment: I see thank you, don't noticed this event, and looking for something like SuppressKeyPress from WinForms :)